# Creating a nested navigation menu in in react with material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I'm trying to create a nested navigation menu with `react` and
`material-ui` by following an example I saw on css-tricks but I'm mainly getting stock on how to make the first menu render the second menu when I click one of the arrow links.

I have created a sandbox here with the code since it will be easier [nested-navigation-menu](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-navigation-example-juv6g?file=/src/App.js)

Here is the [css-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/hamburger-menu-with-a-side-of-react-hooks-and-styled-components/). Here the menu is one level deep, but I would like to make it two level deep.

Thanks in advance